# C# - Multi-threaded producer-consumer pattern where the consumer also produces work

Tags: c#, .net, multithreading

Assume I have Producer-Consumer pattern where the consumer can also produce additional work. Essentially, imagine a list with 1000 integers:

```
var LL = new List<int> {1, 2, 3, ....., 1000};
```

I want to multi-thread sum - so I am taking 2 numbers at a time, summing them and adding the result back to `LL`. I would do this until there is only 1 entry left in `LL` when the last outstanding thread returns.

My experimental code looks like this:

```
var LL = Enumerable.Range(1, 1000).ToList();                             
Func<int, int, int> sum = (a, b) => { return a + b; };
object o = new object();
int outstandingThreads = 0;
while (LL.Count > 1 || outstandingThreads > 0)
{
    //Note that I set an upper bound of 8 simulateneous Threads
    if (LL.Count > 1 && outstandingThreads < 8)
    {
        var l1 = LL[0];
        LL.RemoveAt(0);
        var l2 = LL[0];
        LL.RemoveAt(0);
        Interlocked.Increment(ref outstandingThreads);
        var t = Task.Factory.StartNew(() =>
        {
            var rr = l1 + l2;
            // In practice I would use a ConcurrentBag and not explicitly log
            lock (o)
            {
                LL.Add(rr);                                
            }
            Interlocked.Decrement(ref outstandingThreads);

        }, CancellationToken.None,
        TaskCreationOptions.DenyChildAttach,
        TaskScheduler.Default);
    }                    
}
```

I'm scratching my head as this is not working. I get a different result almost every time. I must be hitting a race condition that I cannot see. Please note, that processing a List is not my actual test case, just a simplification. If there's a better pattern I could be using, I'm also all ears. Multithreading, as you can see, is not my forte.

Comment: Why don't you use a [`BlockingCollection`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.concurrent.blockingcollection-1), or an asynchronous queue like the [`BufferBlock`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.tasks.dataflow.bufferblock-1) or the [`Channel`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.channels.channel-1)? Using specialized producer-consumer tools is simpler and more robust.

Comment: I just didn't know about them - not much experience here. I will look into it though, Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You've got a `lock` around `Add`, but `RemoveAt` is also modification of the list.
Why no `lock` around that?

A race may happen between .Add from worker thread and .RemoveAt from main thread, and it could screw up the .Count property that the List caches (calculating .Count by walking the whole list would be an overkill, so the List caches it for sure), as both Add and Remove do two things: modify the list items and update the .Count, even if it doesn't crash, it may get messed up, so yeah, I think that's it.

Comment: OMG -I blame being cooped up. Thanks :-) Will accept as answer when system lets me.